# How to play persian ney with interdental emboucher sound of letter p

Tags: flute, embouchure

Traditionally [ney](https://www.nfaonline.org/docs/default-source/committees-documents/global-flutes-committee/the-persian-ney.pdf?sfvrsn=9ba5a856_2) is playing with directing air toward edge of ney's end to produce sound, This is doing with tong shape approximately like when telling 'shhhh' or 'tttttt', But [Kianinejad](https://fa.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D9%85%D8%AD%D9%85%D8%AF%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C_%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%A7%D9%86%DB%8C%E2%80%8C%D9%86%DA%98%D8%A7%D8%AF) has been invented a new approch called playing ney with some way like saying 'ppppppp' or 'hhhhhhhhh'. I can't find exact material explaining it, if someone know it please. describe it. I wan't to learn to play in this manner too.

In [this](https://www.aparat.com/v/r31zx) video I found awkward afford of him to teach his approch in persian.